# TIMESTAMPDIFF returns the wrong number of months in mysql

Tags: mysql

If we add the 1 month to the DATE_ADD

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2023-01-31 07:26:35', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Which returns the date 2023-02-28 07:26:35

While if we calculate with TIMESTAMPDIFF it return the 0 as number of month which i guess needs to be 1?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2023-01-31 07:26:35', '2023-02-28 07:26:35')
```

Please let me know where the issue is.

Comment: As a guess towards your second example, `TIMESTAMPDIFF` is called on a date only 3 days in the future. No matter what month you look at, `3` days is less than the `total` days in a month, and thus `3/total == 0`. If `TIMESTAMPADD` considers adding `1 MONTH` to the first date as `2023-02-28 07:26:35`, then any date before then must denote an interval less than `1 MONTH`

Comment: sorry i edit the question as i mention the wrong Date earlier

Comment: You say that `01-31 - 02-28 = 1 month`. Would you say that `01-30 - 02-27 = 1 month`? Can you provide more context about the values these dates can potentially have in your data?

Comment: I believe that it should return 1 month in 01-31 - 02-28 case and in case of 01-30 - 02-27 it should not return 1 month. The context behind this is i have to calculate the package price Againt month and days. like if value comes 1 month and few days then i will have to do the calculation based on this

Answer (score 0):

The function works in such a way that it checks how many literal months are completed from the start date to the end date. It doesn't matter how off the number in the month segment of the start date from that of the end date.

A full month needs to be completed from date to date.

The following question will answer your question: "can it be considered that a full month has been passed from 02/15 to 03/10 ?"

Check the following result out

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2023-01-31', '2023-02-03') // 0
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-01-31','2003-02-28'); //0
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-01-31','2003-02-28'); //Null (not a leap year)

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2003-01-31','2003-03-01'); //1
```

The function calculates the difference the way it would be done by a human.

Comment: Second example should be 1 in my view since feb has only 28 days, same result occurs with 05/31 to 06/30 but 1 is returned for 06/30 to 07/30 so what does timestampdiff consider a full month?

Comment: @P.Salmon If you have two dates like 02/15 and 03/15, do you consider 28 days or 31 days as a month when you're about to do the difference?

Comment: Then why does it return the 28 Feb as complete month when we do  *SELECT DATE_ADD('2023-01-31 07:26:35', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)*

Comment: @Asad `DATE_ADD` works differently. It returns 28 Feb as a complete month because MySQL checks your current month (January) and knows that you want a day from one month later (February), whose maximum value is the last day. Going in overflow on 31 February will automatically truncate to 28, it does not consider 28 nor 31 days difference.

Comment: @lemon is there a way i can get the same result from the both?

Comment: @Asad I think a way to get out of the rabbit hole is using `DATE_ADD` in place of `DATE_DIFF`, if you know that you can have 1 month difference and no more than that. If you can have 2 months of difference or more, there's no solution that can stand imo, apart from a manual check inside your query, with days matching the corresponding month.

Comment: It would be useful if someone who understands what timestaffdiff considers a month could contribute.

Comment: @lemon your suggestion 'Date_Add' make me to come up with the way around which is not much nice but would do my work. I have another table with name seq which have series of number from 1 to 44620. so i just used it for my logic. 'SELECT 
 MAX(DATE_ADD("2023-01-31 07:26:35", INTERVAL ID MONTH)), ID as month
FROM Seq
WHERE 
 ID <= 100
 AND DATE_ADD("2023-01-31 07:26:35", INTERVAL ID MONTH) <= "2023-02-28 07:26:35";'

Comment: Glad it was helpful. You can have that as a temporary solution and maybe improve it if someone comes with a better solution. At least it'll work for the moment @Asad